# want to create .bat file to run ccleaner automatically

Tags: batch-file

I want to do Scheduled Tasks for clean my computer.So that i created .bat file to run program .i.e.
`start /d "C:\Programfile\cclener" ccleaner.exe

From this cclener.exe can open but problem is that after opening one tab is there in ccleaner that is "clean" which need manual interference to click that tab. I want to create program along with above one to run cleane automatically and after one hour of time gap other program will run that is `taskkill /IM ccleaner.exe` to close that program.

the program will be like this

```
start /d "C:\Programfile\cclener" cclener.exe
.........
...........
..........
(In the above "..." program need to write to click the TAB "clean")  
..........  
(Then program to maintain a time gap for 1 hour)  
taskkill /IM ccleaner.exe
```

Comment: Why not simply create a scheduled task? You can specify to kill the executed task after 1 hour and you wouldn't need any batch files for that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read this: http://www.piriform.com/docs/ccleaner/advanced-usage/command-line-parameters

Answer (score 0):

I think ccleaner has parameters to start a clean automatically (this is normal on such programms, try to search for this)
***Edit**: look at Edwins post :-)

I think its not possible to "click" a tab and a button in a programm via batch file.
You can achive this using AutoIt Script:

http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

There you can move the mouse and click some button for example.
to kill the task I would use the autokill function from the taskmanagement from win7 (if you are using win7) in the taskproperties you can say when the task should be killed if its not finished successfuly.

hope this helps.
best regards, noone.